# A quick way to merge all object while keeping all extra data and modifiers?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, export

I was trying to export model I made to the game engine, but it was made of a lot of smaller object, so I wanted to merge them before doing so.

The issue is.. something always breaks when I do so.
-If I use Boolean to merge them - vertex groups get lost, and so is the skinning.
-If I apply all the modifiers, join everything with Ctrl + J, then apply Armature modifier again - normal transfer I did in separate objects get lost. Setting them up again may work, but there are a lot of them and they all have masks, so doing it everything by hand each time I want to export the model will take too much time.

Is there some good way to do so?

Comment: The only way to do this would be to have all the modifiers applied on the final merged mesh, with Vertex Groups to turn them on and off on different areas. Not only is this not practical, it's costly and not possible for every modifier.
You shouldn't need to merge your meshes when exporting, the exporter should be able to apply everything and merge according to the settings you chose

Comment: I see. What format exporter can do this? I'm using FBX now, but I didn't see any "merge" options there. And Unity's importer go no merge options as well.

Answer (score 0):

follow up as answer for the convenience of image:

[image: fbx exporter]

This is the settings for the fbx exporter, when you're choosing the file name.

There are no specificially merge options because the process of exporting will merge everything set to be exported. You can limit this with the **Selected Objects** and **Active Collection** switches.

You also have a switch for the application of your modifiers.

Comment: Hmm? It does not really merge everything - it does apply modifiers, but when I import mesh in Unity - I still have separate objects for each object I had in Blender. And yes, I can select what I export with those options you mentioned, and I used them.

Comment: do you have them under the same collection ?

Comment: I have all them in single collection, then some of they are in different sub-collections. I tried moving them all in single one and exported, but it changed nothing.